# Keyboard rotation when rotate UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikeyboard

I would like to know if there is a possibility to rotate the keyboard when rotate only the view (`UIView` not the `UIViewController`).
The view is on landscape mode, but the keyboard is keeping the portrait mode.

```
 self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
 self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI * (90) / 180.0));
 self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.height,    self.view.frame.size.width);
```

Any idea ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to rotate the native keyboard of the iPhone, If you wanted to rotate the keyboard then you definitely have to change the orientation of the phone.